# Jquery ui tabs load tab content only when tab is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface, tabs

I am using jquery ui tab 
i want to load tab content only when  tab is clicked.
tab content is getting dyanamically through ajax

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="tabs" >
        <ul>
           <li ><a href="#tabs-1" >new tab1</a> </li>
           <li ><a href="#tabs-2" >new tab2</a> </li>
        </ul>
       <div id="tabs-1">
              Tab 1
       </div>
       <div id="tabs-2">
              Tab 2
       </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please provide some more information about what you've tried, and your existing Javascript code?

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery UI tab**

I have done this using jquery tab **show** and based on you need you can also try **beforeLoad**,**load**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UfaH5/)

**html**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Bar</a></li>
    </ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
   Tab1 
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    Tabe2
</div>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
 $("#tabs").tabs({
    show: function( e,ui ){
        alert("working");
        $( ui.panel ).html('<p>Load ajax here...</p>');
            $.ajax({
                url:'',
                type:'',
                success:function(){

                }
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: Removed: show event [jQuery UI 1.10 changelog](http://jqueryui.com/changelog/1.10.0)
Use  `activate` or `beforeActivate`

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the Tabs in `PHP` by giving random ids.

```
<div class="load_content" id="tabs" >
    <ul>
    <li ><a href="#tabs-1" >new tab1</a> </li>
    <li ><a href="#tabs-2" >new tab2</a> </li>
    </ul>
```

### jQuery

```
   $(".load_content").click(function () {
        tabId = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "your/desried/path",
            data: tabId,
            success: function (data) {
                $(this).html(data);
            }
        });
    })
```